# Text wrangling: How can I get just the key comment from authorized_keys?

Tags: ssh, gnu

Auditing some servers, I need a list of the comments on all the authorised keys in the authorized_keys file.

How can I cut this file to display a list of comments, eg user@host?

Anything can appear before the Key, including spaces

The Key Comment appears directly after the key

The Key Comment is the last item in the line

The Key Comment can contain spaces

The Key is the longest field on each line

It is desired that the key comment *only* is extracted from each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to include `/^==/` lines:

```
perl -nE 'if (/^==/) { print }
          elsif (!/^#/ and ($c) = /\b\w+\s+AAAA\S+(.*)$/)
            { $c =~ s/^\s+//; say $c || "<no comment>" }'
```

GNU sed (using POSIX Extended regexen):

```
sed -nr '/^==/{p; d}; /^#/d;
         /.*\<\w+\s+AAAA\S+/{s///; s/^\s+//; s/^$/<no comment>/; p}'
```

This will skip disabled (commented out) keys, and [mostly] correctly handle lines containing per-key options (e.g. `from="1.2.3.4" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EA my comment`).

Note that comments are practically meaningless – comparing the key fingerprints might be better in some cases.

Comment: I don't always have Perl available, unfortunately.

Comment: @Blazemore: Do you have `sed`?` The regex grawity gave is a good starting point. Taking into account that `sed` doesn't offer PCRE, and taking a few shortcuts, I came up with `sed -e s/^#.*// -e s/.*AAAA[^\ ]+// -e s/^\ +// ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Doesn't work on my system, just prints every line in full

Comment: @Blazemore: If your display breaks at the same place as mine, note that there is a space after AAAA[^\. You might want to study regular expressions, they are mightily helpful.

Comment: @Blazemore: Are you doing the audit remotely (connected from another machine)? You could do `ssh targethost cat .ssh/authorized_keys | perl ...`

Comment: @Blazemore: Also, I have added an identical GNU sed version.

Comment: Thanks, that sed one works perfectly. On an unrelated note, do you know how to also get it to allow lines that start with a double equals (==)?

Comment: @Blazemore: Is that even valid syntax for OpenSSH? (Also, do you need the entire ==..... line, or just the comment field in it?)

Comment: Entire == line, it's coming from something else (tail -n)

Comment: @Blazemore: See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I `cut`...

Exactly.

`cut -d' ' -f3- .ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: This relies on keys being in a very specific format. If the comment part isn't the exact correct field, it fails.

Comment: @Blazemore: I admit I was ignorant of the specialities that grawity hinted at. Ignore my answer if it does not float your boat, this works only for "off the mill" authorized_keys.

Comment: @DevSolar you could self-delete the answer.  Though it is a good general purpose answer that would work well for most people needing a similar answer.  And simplicity makes it easier to understand.